# Handling XInput in UWP

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp

In UWP there is support for XBox gamepads via XInput. In C# we have `Windows.Gaming.Input` namespace with Gamepad class, in C++ we have `Xinput.h`. Both work fine with one exception - I have to connect and turn on my gamepad before starting my app. After starting the app the gamepad will not be detected (for example `Gamepad.GamepadAdded` event will not fired). Is there a way to detect gamepad when it's turned on/connected after the UWP app has been launched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion for you is to check the connection status time by time. One simple approach is to use [DispatcherTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.aspx). Here is a [sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/A-Simple-Timer-for-c115b761) for DispatcherTimer. You can start a timer in OnLaunch().

In the dispatcherTimer.Tick callback function, you can check the gamepad connection by Gamepad.GetState() and currentState.IsConnected property. In this [post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203900.aspx) you can find how to check Gamepad connection status.
I hope this can help.